# I dont know CFRelease(CFTypeRef cf) usage when i using the Core Text

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Using the Core Text, i dont know when should i call the release function:

void CFRelease (
   CFTypeRef cf
);

should i call above function passing following parameters:

CGContextRef contextRef;

CGMutablePathRef leftColumnPath;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call CFRelease unless you create/copy them.

> Core Foundation functions have names that indicate when you own a returned object:
>   Object-creation functions that have “Create” embedded in the name;
>   Object-duplication functions that have “Copy” embedded in the name.
>   If you own an object, it is your responsibility to relinquish ownership (using CFRelease) when you have finished with it.

So if you use some CF method in which contains "Copy" or "Create", you should call CFRelease on them. Else you can just use them.

Comment: do you mean following:CGMutablePathRef leftColumnPath = CGPathCreateMutable(); when i call this Creat function, i should call the CFRelease?

Comment: This is a very simple test.  Does the method have the word "Copy" or "Create" in it?  If yes, you must release it.  If no, you must *not* release it.

Comment: I see, when i call the CF methods contains "Copy" or "Create", “CG” Methods does not! Thanks!

Comment: @jeffrey You HAVE TO call release method for your situation. You created a path by calling a "Create" method `CGPathCreateMutable`, so when you finished using it, you should call `CGPathRelease` on it.
PS. In fact, CGXXXRelease is the same as CFRelease. The only difference is "specified release method"(like CGPathRelease) can apply a NULL as input, while CFRelease can not. In your situation, you can call either CFRelease or CGPathRelease to avoid leak.